# display number in dashboard to start from 1 every year

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a table that I wish to display in my .php file, as it will display every number of each row but when it comes to a brand new year, it will changes to begin at 1 once again.

.php file html code:

```
<table id="example">
      <thead>
             <tr>
             <th style="width: 40px">Year</th>
             <th style="width: 40px">Id</th>
             </tr>
     </thead>
<tbody>
<?php
include('include/config1.php');
$query = "SELECT * from table ORDER BY Id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php
     if($row['status']!=3){ //display the year from the date according to status
       echo date("Y",strtotime($row['sdate'])); }
     else{
       echo date("Y",strtotime($row['ssdate']));
     } ?>
     //the years are the same for both columns in each row
</td>

<td>//The ID that auto starts from 1 every year with an increment of 1 to the newest (not the same as the unique id from the table </td>

<?php}?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What kind of javascript functions I must implement to make this work?

NOTE: all the data inserted into the MySQL table will not be removed from the database, the status will only change to delete, that's all.

Comment: JavaScript? Isn't this just a simple loop?

Comment: loop? how to loop it after taking out from mysql?

Comment: Well, just like any other loop in php, right?

Comment: like there's increment but when it comes to a brand new year it will goes from 1 again, can it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, If you want your records to be sorted year after year, you also have to sort by the `date` field!

```
"SELECT * from table ORDER BY sdate,Id DESC";
```

And secondly you will have to remember your previous year in a loop, and compare it to the current. If it is different, then reset your ID to `1`

```
<?php
    include('include/config1.php');
    $query = "SELECT * from table ORDER BY sdate, Id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $currentYear = null;
    $data = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $year = ($row['status'] == 3) ? date("Y", strtotime($row['ssdate'])) : date("Y", strtotime($row['sdate']));

        $data[$year][] = $row;                     
    }
?>

<table id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 40px">Year</th>
        <th style="width: 40px">Id</th>
        <th style="width: 80px">Machine No</th>
        <th style="width: 80px">Project Name</th>
        <th style="width: 80px">PIC</th>
        <th style="width: 80px">Purpose of Service</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
    foreach ($data as $year => $oneYear) {
        for ($i = count($oneYear); $i >= 1; $i--) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $year ?></td>
        <td><?= $i ?></td>
        <td><?= $oneYear[$i]['Machine_No']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $oneYear[$i]['projectName']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $oneYear[$i]['pic']; ?></td>
        <td><?= substr(str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $row['Purpose_of_Service']), 0, 50); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi! it worked but I wish it to display the id increment in desc order not having the latest to row to begin at 1

Comment: @Lim I've updated my answer to show the records in descending order.
P.S. Please consider upvoting for the answer if it did help you.

Comment: Of course! the increment id display out in the id column still begin at 1 as what you've changed is just the order of the id in the table to be display in desc, which is correct, but the oldest data display out is (the max count of the row of that year) and the latest display is 1, which is the problem

Comment: I wish for the latest 1d of the year to be the (max increment of the year) and the oldest of the id is begin at 1 `SELECT * from table ORDER BY sdate DESC` will do just fine to display the latest year out

Comment: @Lim In this case I would suggest to store the result in the temporarry array `$data`, and looping backwards throug it elements. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: the increment worked but when I wish to add other values columns of the rows in, they are gone

Comment: Allow me to insert my latest code for you in my answer reply

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Dmitriy Gritsenko's Help I've managed to did it, but the problem is that the other data from the columns of the table couldn't be display

```
<table id="example" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 40px">Year</th>
                <th style="width: 40px">Id</th>
                <th style="width: 80px">Machine No</th>
                <th style="width: 80px">Project Name</th>
                <th style="width: 80px">PIC</th>
                <th style="width: 80px">Purpose of Service</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php

                include('include/config1.php');
                $query = "SELECT * from table ORDER BY sdate DESC, Id DESC";
                $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

                $currentYear = null;
                $data = [];
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $year = ($row['status'] == 3) ? date("Y", strtotime($row['ssdate'])) : date("Y", strtotime($row['sdate']));

                    $data[$year][] = $row;                     
                }
                foreach ($data as $year => $oneYear) {
                    for ($i = count($oneYear); $i >= 1; $i--) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $year ?></td>
                <td><?= $i ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Machine_No']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['projectName']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['pic']; ?></td>

                <td><?php 
                   $row['Purpose_of_Service'] =substr( $row['Purpose_of_Service'],0,50);
                    echo (str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $row['Purpose_of_Service'])); 
                    ?>
                </td>

             <?php
                }}
            ?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your additional information